# Replace rear deraileur without breaking the chain

Tags: derailleur, cassette, derailleur-rear

I currently have a Shimano Dura Ace 10 speed rear derailleur with a 12-25 cassette. For some hilly rides I'd like to change to a 12-30 cassette.

The maximum the rear derailleur can handle is 28, so I'm thinking of getting a Shimano 105 RD. I'd like to be able to switch between these two set-ups but fear that breaking the chain each time is not a good thing to do.

Is it possible to change the RD without breaking the chain by taking apart the pulley wheels?

Also is it possible to fit a 12-30 cassette on a Shimano Dura Ace 10 speed short cage RD?

Comment: Put on the 12-30 cassette and try (carefully). It might work if you DON'T CROSS the gears but most likely the chain is too short. Also, you can fit a derailleur by taking apart the cage.

Comment: Did you consider adding reusable missing link to your chain? This way it's possible to remove chain without compromising the integrity.

Comment: Yes you can do it, and I have. In an emergency. Once. But as @Batman says, doing it repeatedly is risky. You could discover that you've lost a jockey wheel in the middle of a ride. That would be somewhat uncomfortable.

Comment: What about getting it out of the front derailleur?

Comment: In a shop you can disassemble the derailer to free the chain, but you need to be in a place with a clean floor so you can find the parts you drop.

Comment: You'll just have to use the right amount of torque when you tighten the two bolts holding the jockey wheels. Same applies when you replace the jockey wheels.

Comment: @Blam - Good point. I think in this case, the idea is you have a chain long enough for both cassettes, remove the wheel, open the rear derailleur to swap in one which can take a bigger cassette without removing the chain from the bike. But the whole exercise is somewhat inane given that you can just leave the bigger capacity derailleur on and deal with a few extra links when using the smaller cassette.

Comment: @Batman The question confuses a bit of stuff.  I would expect more from a physics graduate.

Comment: Can't you can simply put a smaller ring in your crank? Assuming you also have a dura ace crank, you can put a  50-34T chainring on, which should be enough, no?

Comment: @super I already have a compact (50-34) crank. Some of the hills near me are pretty severe up to 25% gradient so a 34-32 will allow me to spin up them nicely rather than grind my way up.

Comment: Ok. Here are the status for your derailleur: Maximum Sprocket: 28T, Maximum Front Difference: 16T; Total Capacity: 33T. I would say a 12-27T cassette is enough for you. A 34 front - 27 rear relation sounds pretty light. Otherwise, I think your best option is to sell your cassette and derailleur and get Ultegra, which exists with a medium cage and supports a maxium of 40T, so you can get a really high cassette. This parts are not easily interchangeable so I don't think doing so is a viable option and you will get tired of it

Comment: Have you considered changing your Crank set / chain ring size? Easier to do and same benefit.

Comment: If you fit a chain and derailleur that will handle the 12-30 then you should only need to swap the cassette  between rides because 12-25 is a subset of 12-30.

Comment: Rather than swap between rides, have you considered a triple chain ring  Although it would cost more to setup, front and back derailleurs, new crankset) you could stick with the 12/25 and have closer ratios than the 12-30, and completely avoid rebuilding the bike between rides.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're likely to destroy the derailleur by doing that too many times.

KMC and [Wipperman](http://www.connexchain.com/en/product/connex-link.html) both have 10 speed quick links which are a better thing to do. Note that you'll need a chain big enough for the larger cassette (or, with a quick link have 2 chains).

Comment: This not true, unless you are incompetent with your tools. There is no issue with disassembling the dérailleur to remove it.

Comment: @zenbike - derailleurs have Loctite on the screws that hold the cage together. Unless your are refreshing this eventually the screws will be able to work themselves loose.

Comment: @DWGKNZ: Yes. You need to do the job correctly.  That doesn't make it unsafe to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to remove your rear dérailleur without damaging it. Care should be taken (as with any job) not to damage the machine screws that hold the dérailleur cage together, or to lose the pulleys or screws.

The pulleys do come in multiple pieces, so real care should be taken.

As for fitting a 12-30 cassette on a short cage dura ace 10 speed dérailleur, Shimano says 28t is the maximum. You may be able to fit a 30t if you avoid cross-chaining, but it's better not go take that risk, as the failure consequences can be quite high.